# I have an error when try to install discord.py on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: python, pip, ubuntu-14.04

> pip3 install discord.py

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 1479, in <module>
    register_loader_type(importlib_bootstrap.SourceFileLoader, DefaultProvider)
AttributeError: module 'importlib._bootstrap' has no attribute 'SourceFileLoader'
```

I try python3.6 and python3.7. Anyway it's work the same way.

Comment: apparently, discord.py is not compatible with Python3.7,
can you try this suggested command : 
`python -m pip install -U https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/archive/rewrite.zip#egg=discord.py[voice]`

Comment: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 278, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1198, in prepare_files
    do_download,

Comment: File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1376, in unpack_url
    self.session,
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 546, in unpack_http_url
    resp = session.get(target_url, stream=True)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 479, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 237, in request
    return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)

Comment: File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 467, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 570, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/adapters.py", line 385, in send
    raise SSLError(e)
SSLError: [Errno 8] _ssl.c:510: EOF occurred in violation of protocol

Storing debug log for failure in /home/raisa/.pip/pip.log

Comment: try installing security packages for requests :
`pip install --force-reinstall requests[security]`